# Does it affect our credit score if we refinance one mortgage and apply for a new one within a short span?

Tags: mortgage, credit-score

We're considering moving from our current home by purchasing a new one prior to selling the old one. However, we refinanced the loan on our current home less than a full year ago (approx 9 months ago). Since we will need to take out another loan for the new home prior to selling our old home (and using the proceeds to pay off the old loan, of course), would this affect our credit score in any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anytime you have a hard pull on your credit, it will negatively affect it, but the impact is fairly minor compared to other things.

http://www.myfico.com/crediteducation/questions/inquiry-credit-score.aspx

Comment: Interesting, it says "Time since credit inquiry(ies)" is a factor though it is not clear how significant. Thanks.

Comment: Credit inquiries fall off your credit report after 18-24 months. Unless you applied for 10 credits in the last two years, it is nothing to worry about. A hard pull reduces your credit score by a few points. Since your credit worthiness is in a range... unless those few points put you in a lower bracket, it is nothing to worry about.